# Why won't this piece of my code write to file

Tags: c++, string, loops, fstream, sstream

I am developing a C++ banking system.
I am able to get the float, newbal, values correctly and when I try to write to file, there is no data in the file.

```
else if (x == 2)
{
    cout << "You have selected option number 2. Deposit.\n";
    cout << "Please enter you account ID: ";
    cin >> ID;
    file.open("C:\\Users\\Raggulddon\\Desktop\\C++ supplement\\Cust_" + ID + ".dat", ios:: in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Sorry the requested account could not be located.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        file >> firstname >> lastname;
        cout << endl << firstname << " " << lastname << endl;
        cout << "-----------------------------------\n";
        string line;
        while (getline(file, line))
        {

            // stringstream the getline for line string in file
            istringstream iss(line);

            if (iss >> date >> amount)
            {
                cout << date << "\t\t$" << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(2) << amount << endl;
                famount += amount;
            }

        }
        cout << "Your balance is $" << famount << endl;
        cout << "How much would you like to deposit today: $";
        cin >> amountinput;

        float newbal = 0;
        newbal = (famount += amountinput);


        cout << "\nYour new balance is: $" << newbal << ".\n";
        file << date << "\t\t" << newbal; //***This should be writing to file
        but it doesn 't.
            
file.close();
```

The text file looks like this:

> Tony Gaddis
>
> 05/24/12 100
>
> 05/30/12 300
>
> 07/01/12 -300
>
> // Console Output looks like this
>
> Tony Gaddis
>
> 05/24/12 100
>
> 05/30/12 300
>
> 07/01/12 -300
>
> Your balance is: #1
>
> How much wuld you like to deposit: #2
>
> Your new balance is: #1 + #2
>
> write to file
>
> close file.
>
> // exits to main loop::::

How can I make it write to file and save it, and why is this happening.

I tried doing it with `ostringstream` as well considering how I used `istringstream` for the input. But it didn't work either:

```
float newbal=0;
newbal = (famount += amountinput);

ostringstream oss(newbal);
oss << date << "\t\t" << newbal;
```

I am trying to self teach C++ so any relevant information would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: There's a reason you should check for errors when reading and writing.  By the time you try to write the eof flag is likely set on the file since you read everything from it.

Comment: My question is: Why will this not write to file file<<date<<"\t\t"<<newbal; I am not using classes. @ninja how do I write to end of file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a text file, you should not use "ios::binary", when opening the file.